What does passing a ref to an element component do in React?
I always assumed refs in React were one-directional references. In other words, I thought that if I did:
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  return <span ref={ref}>abc</span>
}

the ref wouldn't have any impact on the <span> at all; it would just let SomeComponent access the <span>'s DOM element.
However, I recently discovered that's not the case: the ref can actually impact the element it's passed in to. In a slight variation of the above, where I have the ref passed in:
const SomeComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <span ref={ref}>abc</span>
});

The passed-in ref can actually make React not render the child ('abc' in my example) of the <span>. Everything works as normal (there are no errors), but it renders as <span></span>.
What does passing a ref into a component actually do to the component itself? In particular, how could what the ref contains impact the rendering of the component?
I've tried reading the React docs, but they don't seem to cover this, so I came here.

The passed-in ref can actually make React not render the child ('abc' in my example) of the <span>. Unless you're doing something really weird with the ref in the parent component, that won't happen. Can you show some example code that demonstrates that behavior? Here's an example that does not show the behavior: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/thirsty-jennings-p5dkl9?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A16%2C1

Indeed the OP is definitely doing something really weird, but once you have a reference to a DOM node you can innerHTML = ‘’ to your hearts delight

The answer to this question is in the docs, so maybe you didn’t find the right page or something

@Adam Jenkins the docs discuss using a ref, after you have passed it to a component, but I'm asking about what happens when you pass it to the component.  Again, you can literally have <span ref={someRef}>abc</span> and the contents of someRef can make the "abc" not render; that has nothing to do with using ref.current.whateverDomMethod after the component has rendered.

@NicholasTower The code in question is not easy to just sum up (the ref is being passed through several components), but I'll try to make a basic repro.

Well, after debugging for a bit I still don't have a clean repro, but I can see from logs that the component is rendering properly initially, so it has to be that some logic higher up is changing the ref.  That makes your answer perfect, thank you!


what does passing a ref into a component actually do to the component itself?

If you pass in a ref object (an object with a .current property), then react will assign the dom element to .current and do nothing else.
If you pass in a ref function, then react will call that function and pass in the dom element. In principal this function could do anything, so if you write a weird function, you can wipe out the contents of the element. But most commonly, you'll just assign the element to some property of some object, much like what react did automatically with the ref object.

In particular, how could what the ref contains impact the rendering of the component?

The only way it would do that is if you write code that changes the element. Out of the box a ref is completely passive.
